# Form errors are displayed at the wrong place

Tags: python, django, templates

I am working on my Blog website and in the registration template I should insert the username and email and password so I can register but if i have an error it should give me what is it BUT every error I have it goes to the bottom of the template, not under the field I want.

P.S.: I am using Django framework!!

template.html:

```
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com" name="username">
            <label for="floatingInput">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com" name="email">
            <label for="floatingInput">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password1">
            <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
            <input type="password" class="form-control mt-3" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password2">
            <label for="floatingPassword">Re-Type Password</label>
        </div>
        
        {% if forms.errors %}
        {% for field in forms %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <h5 style="color: red;">{{ error|escape }}</h5>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for error in forms.non_field_errors %}
            <h5 style="color: red;">{{ error|escape }}</h5>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %} <br>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

if anything needs to be added other then the template please tell me in the comment!!

Thanks in advance!! <3

Comment: Well you are rendering the errors at the bottom? So what do you expect?

Comment: Your approach is wrong you need to iterate the form and errors at the same time. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that what i mean how i can specify for wich field i want the error to appear so i can move it to the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You render the field errors at the bottom as well, hence the error. In order to render the errors of a specific field, you should iterate over the errors of that field, so:

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    {% for error in forms.username.errors %}
        <h5 style="color: red;">{{ error|escape }}</h5>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com" name="username">
    <label for="floatingInput">Username</label>
</div>
```

and this for all fields of course.